# When i run pandas read_html function it just says no table was found any idea why it is unable to find it?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to save some tables into a pandas dataframe from this page. https://www.rmb.co.za/fixed-income-rates

I have inspected the table and it is a html table but it can't seem to find it. Is there something I'm missing as this code works for wikipedia pages for example.

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.rmb.co.za/fixed-income-rates'
swaps = pd.read_html(url)

print(swaps)
```

Comment: You might consider looking at the HTML source for the page and see if the tabular data in the page is encoded in the way that pandas expects.

Comment: There is no `<table>` element in the source for that page.

Comment: Yeah strange I am able to see the table element when i inspect it but it isn't in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I think due to the delay in loading of the table in the website, you're only getting this section without the table. Try to create a code to save a copy of the html file locally before reading the .html file with the table elements completely loaded.

```
<section class="container container-l">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-l-2"/>
<div class="col-l-8">
<div id="fixed-income-table">
****** Missing Table elements *******
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```